# Screen's build method triggered when I use the navigator with rootNavigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

There is an interesting problem. I'm using Flutter 2.0 in my app. It has a bottom navigation bar. When I push to the new screen using "Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)" along with the new screen, the screen that provides navigation is also rebuilding.

**CategoriesView build() method**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   print("Building: CategoryView");
   return mobileBody;
}
```

**ProductDetailView build() method**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building: ProductDetailView");
    return mobileBody;
  }
```

When i use the "context.rootNavigator.pushNamed(ProductDetailView.route);" in CategoryView output is:

```
I/flutter (21910): Building: ProductDetailView
I/flutter (21910): Building: CategoryView
```

Without rootNavigator output is (context.navigator.pushNamed(ProductDetailView.route);):

```
I/flutter (21910): Building: ProductDetailView
```

**Navigator extensions:**

```
extension NavigationExtension on BuildContext {
  NavigatorState get rootNavigator => Navigator.of(this, rootNavigator: true);
  NavigatorState get navigator => Navigator.of(this);
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?

Comment: i have the same problem, discussed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80354

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue too, currently use a `StatefulWidget` wrapper for it.

```dart
class WrapperStateless extends StatefulWidget {
  const WrapperStateless({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WrapperStatelessState createState() => _WrapperStatelessState();
}

class _WrapperStatelessState extends State<WrapperStateless> {
  TabA tabA;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabA = TabA();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return tabA;
    return tabA;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(WrapperStateless oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    // setState(() {});
  }
}
```